# How to reduce table duplication, while ensuring integrity of the database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

For example, in my app I have some class called Contact:

```
case class Contact(name: String, email: String, phone: String)
```

And several other classes have one-to-many relation to that contact (for example, there are Companies and Houses).

Currently, I have database table for Contacts set up as something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Contacts` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `entityId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `entityType` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(300),
 `phone` varchar(300),
 `email` varchar(300),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

where `entityType` is storing the "code" that determines the entity type this contact belongs to (1 for Company, 2 for House, etc), and `entityId` points to the row in Companies or Houses table. Companies and Houses tables are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `Companies` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `Houses` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

So, when I need to get all contacts for some Company (which has id = 1234 in this example), I execute the following query:

```
select * from Contacts c where c.entityType = 1 and c.entityId = 1234;
```

Now, I understand that this is awful - at the very least, I can't create a foreign key on entityId, thus I can't ensure that my data is consistent.

The alternative will be to create a separate Contacts table for each entity type (CompanyContacts, HouseContacts, etc) but that will result in lots of duplication in both database and application code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: To the downvoter - could you please tell me the reason for the downvote? I'm new to the site, so I probably don't know all the rules, but I need feedback to improve.

Comment: Could you please show some sample data to test ?

Comment: @CORRUPT - Sure. I added the two other tables example definitions, and sample of the query to retrieve the contacts.

Comment: Use The Party Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest to reorganize schema, to make it more scalable.

1. `DROP` columns `entityId` and `entityType`.
2. `CREATE` an `Objects` (or `Entities`) table which will store public / shared information for all objects / entities. It's primary key will migrate to `Companies` and to `Houses` with `1:1` relation. For one object might exist only one company **OR** only one house. Also, you will have to remove `AUTO_INCREMENT` from `Companies` and `Houses`, because in this case they will no longer generate identifiers themselves.
3. Add foreign key to `Contacts` table from shared `Objects` table - contacts might exist for any type of object.

Structure might look like this:

[image: Schema]

You might obtain entity type by following query:

```
SELECT
    cnt.*,
    CASE
        WHEN NOT cmp.id IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN NOT hs.id IS NULL THEN 2
    END as entityType
FROM
    Contacts as cnt
        INNER JOIN Objects as obj ON cnt.objectId = obj.id
        LEFT JOIN Companies as cmp ON cmp.id = obj.id
        LEFT JOIN Houses as hs ON cmp.id = hs.id
```

Also, note that `entityId` becomes `objectId` in this case.

---

Here is a `CREATE`-script for benchmarking and test:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Objects` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shared_property1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `shared_property2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `etc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Companies` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `company_name` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `private_property1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `private_property2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `etc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_Companies_Objects`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `Objects` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Houses` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `private_property1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `private_property2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `etc` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_Houses_Objects`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id`)
    REFERENCES `Objects` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Contacts` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `objectId` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(300) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  INDEX `FK_Contacts_Objects` (`objectId` ASC),

  CONSTRAINT `FK_Contacts_Objects`
    FOREIGN KEY (`objectId`)
    REFERENCES `Objects` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: That is the standard way to model subclassing in ORM's. It is quite a nice approach, with only one drawback (in this situation) - the application code is going to become quite complicated.

Comment: @Rogach Yeah. Still, application code is more easier to change, than a large database records. Another way is to add a lot of foreign keys in a `Contacts` table for each entityType, i.e. `companyId NULL`, `houseId NULL`. But I think it might become an overkill after adding 50-60 entities. Consider.

Comment: As a second thought, given the fact that I almost don't have shared fields between objects in this case (only `id`), the application code actually can stay almost the same. I think that's the best approach.

Comment: @Rogach you might create a view to simplify selection. But `INSERTS` might get complicated for a case, that I've described.

Comment: No, duplicating id columns for each entityType is absolutely horrible - just think about the poor guy who will need to maintain the db after me. He'll probably submit it to DailyWTF ;)

Comment: If I only keep `id` column in the shared `Objects` table, `Houses` and `Companies` can stay exactly the same - no view is even needed.

Comment: And inserts will also need only a minor change - just insert a row into `Objects` and get `last_insert_id` before inserting the whole object.

Comment: @Rogach test it. I hope, it will help. Cheers.